# How to compare interfaces

Tags: ansible

A host might have more than 2 interfaces ["lo","eth0","eth1"]

I want to run a when condition if host has only 2 interfaces ["lo","eth0"]

```
when: 'ansible_interfaces == 2'
```

but it returns:

```
"ansible_interfaces == 2": false
```

It has 2 interfaces why is it false?

Answer (score 1):

you are not comparing the `count` of elements in `ansible_interfaces` to 2, but the value of variable `ansible_interfaces` to 2.

you should use:

`when: ansible_interfaces|length == 2`